# How do I update my graphics drivers?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card

I am using a graphics driver which is about 2 years ago which I downloaded from laptop's vendor site http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4132&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5384730#N5464 and it hasn't been updated since. Is it okay if I just download it from graphics card vendor's site?

Or, does it have something to with laptop's model too?

Comment: Laptops usually have customized cards which require specific drivers. Graphic card manufacturers only provide *generic* drivers, which may not be fully compatible, if at all. Why do you need to update the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of laptop manufacturers [HP included] restrict your graphics drivers to updates provided only by the laptop manufacturer, not the Graphics chip manufacturer.
Unfortunately, this can mean that when they stop providing updated drivers, you're stuck.

Depending on what graphics card is in the machine, try either...
http://support.amd.com/en-us  for ATI/AMD
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx for NVidia or
http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx? for Intel

& see if the drivers they offer will actually install.